# Can I make Visual Studio Professional 2017 work with Dell Display Manager Easy Arrange?

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I am running Windows 10 and have a 42" Dell P4317Q running at 3840x2160. I have installed the Dell Display Manager to use Easy Arrange to snap windows to specific areas. However, Visual Studio doesn't snap to these areas or even show the grid on drag, like all other app windows.

Is there a way to make VS work with Easy Arrange?

Comment: Probably no way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a workaround with my own program (Windows Forms) that is found in https://github.com/Roman-Tarasiuk/WindowsTools. Build it and run, and then from the main menu or system tray icon context menu select Miscellaneous | Screen ruler | Panel...
Using the panel's Form Border context menu item to arrange size of the panel (then you can toggle borders off), move the panel over Visual Studio and use mouse scroll to make the panel ***almost*** transparent. After that, I think, you can make your screenshot. After you have got the screenshot, use the Minimize context menu item of the panel to continue working with Visual Studio.

Comment: Use refreshed version of the solution, because I answered earlier than I have pushed to github 'Minimize' menu item of the panel. :)